# Modify global size of booktabs table

Tags: tables, width, booktabs

Here is the table I am trying to make:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lll}

 \toprule
Conditions & Items test corrects & Items test incorrects \\
 \midrule
 Non-adjacents & Fa\textunderscore Sol\textunderscore Ré\textunderscore (O\textunderscore P\textunderscore Q\textunderscore ) & *Do\#\textunderscore Sol\#\textunderscore Si (S\textunderscore R\textunderscore T) \\
 & Sol\#\textunderscore Do\#\textunderscore Si\textunderscore  (R\textunderscore S\textunderscore T) & *Ré\textunderscore Sol\textunderscore Fa (Q\textunderscore P\textunderscore O) \\
 & \textunderscore Do\textunderscore Fa\#\textunderscore Ré\# (\textunderscore u\textunderscore v\textunderscore w) & *La\textunderscore Mi\textunderscore La\# (\textunderscore y\textunderscore x\textunderscore z) \\
 & \textunderscore Mi\textunderscore La\textunderscore La\# (\textunderscore x\textunderscore y\textunderscore z) & *Ré\#\textunderscore Fa\#\textunderscore Do (\textunderscore w\textunderscore v\textunderscore u) \\
Adjacents &  Ré.Ré\#.Fa.Do.Sol.Fa\# (QwOuPv) & *Si.La.Sol\#.La\#.Do\#.Mi (TyRzSx) \\ 
 & Ré.La\#.Fa.Mi.Sol.La (QzOxPy) & *Si.Fa\#.Sol\#.Ré\#.Do\#.Do (TvRwSu) \\ 
 & Si.Ré\#.Sol\#.Do.Do\#.Fa\# (TwRuSv) & *Ré.La.Fa.La\#.Sol.Mi (QyOzPx) \\ 
 & Si.La\#.Sol\#.Mi.Do\#.La (TzRxSy) & *Ré.Fa\#.Fa.Ré\#.Sol.Do QvOwPu) \\ 
 \bottomrule 

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

The result is as follow:

[image]

I tried to reduce the width of my table with `\footnotesize` but the text in the table is still a bit beyond the right margin:

[image]

**Question:**

Is there a way to force all the table to stay align with the text with booktabs ?

Comment: You have specified a target total width but said that every entry is `l` that is single-line and set to natural width, so tabularx has no way to change the width of the table, You always have to have at least 1 `X` column in `tabularx`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want `tabularx`, in my opinion.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\sh}{$\sharp$}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize

\begin{tabular}{lll}
 \toprule
Conditions & Items test corrects & Items test incorrects \\
 \midrule
Non-adjacents & Fa\_Sol\_Ré\_(O\_P\_Q\_) & *Do\sh\_Sol\sh\_Si (S\_R\_T) \\
 & Sol\sh\_Do\sh\_Si\_ (R\_S\_T) & *Ré\_Sol\_Fa (Q\_P\_O) \\
 & \_Do\_Fa\sh\_Ré\sh (\_u\_v\_w) & *La\_Mi\_La\sh (\_y\_x\_z) \\
 & \_Mi\_La\_La\sh (\_x\_y\_z) & *Ré\sh\_Fa\sh\_Do (\_w\_v\_u) \\
Adjacents &  Ré.Ré\sh.Fa.Do.Sol.Fa\sh (QwOuPv) & *Si.La.Sol\sh.La\sh.Do\sh.Mi (TyRzSx) \\
 & Ré.La\sh.Fa.Mi.Sol.La (QzOxPy) & *Si.Fa\sh.Sol\sh.Ré\sh.Do\sh.Do (TvRwSu) \\
 & Si.Ré\sh.Sol\sh.Do.Do\sh.Fa\sh (TwRuSv) & *Ré.La.Fa.La\sh.Sol.Mi (QyOzPx) \\
 & Si.La\sh.Sol\sh.Mi.Do\sh.La (TzRxSy) & *Ré.Fa\sh.Fa.Ré\sh.Sol.Do QvOwPu) \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

If I try the same with `\begin{tabularx}{lXX}`, I get that one line is split into two rows (with a wrong hyphen, unless I disable hyphenation for the table). A better result is with the specification `@{}lXX@{}`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\sh}{$\sharp$}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\footnotesize
\hyphenpenalty=10000
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}lXX@{}}
 \toprule
Conditions & Items test corrects & Items test incorrects \\
 \midrule
Non-adjacents & Fa\_Sol\_Ré\_(O\_P\_Q\_) & *Do\sh\_Sol\sh\_Si (S\_R\_T) \\
 & Sol\sh\_Do\sh\_Si\_ (R\_S\_T) & *Ré\_Sol\_Fa (Q\_P\_O) \\
 & \_Do\_Fa\sh\_Ré\sh (\_u\_v\_w) & *La\_Mi\_La\sh (\_y\_x\_z) \\
 & \_Mi\_La\_La\sh (\_x\_y\_z) & *Ré\sh\_Fa\sh\_Do (\_w\_v\_u) \\
Adjacents &  Ré.Ré\sh.Fa.Do.Sol.Fa\sh (QwOuPv) & *Si.La.Sol\sh.La\sh.Do\sh.Mi (TyRzSx) \\
 & Ré.La\sh.Fa.Mi.Sol.La (QzOxPy) & *Si.Fa\sh.Sol\sh.Ré\sh.Do\sh.Do (TvRwSu) \\
 & Si.Ré\sh.Sol\sh.Do.Do\sh.Fa\sh (TwRuSv) & *Ré.La.Fa.La\sh.Sol.Mi (QyOzPx) \\
 & Si.La\sh.Sol\sh.Mi.Do\sh.La (TzRxSy) & *Ré.Fa\sh.Fa.Ré\sh.Sol.Do QvOwPu) \\
 \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

However, the result will change with the text width.

[image]

Note that `tabularx` ***needs*** at least an `X` column in order to work.

Note also that `\#` is not the correct symbol for a sharp. I defined `\sh` as `$\sharp$` (the `\sharp` command is only available in math mode, by default).

Comment: Thanks! It is working great without `tabularx` and with `footnotesize`. Thanks for the symbol formatting tips also !

Answer (score 3):

`l` (`c` and `r` too) column will not break when the content reaches some limit. Since you are using `tabularx` with a total width of `\textwidth` you wil be better off with

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX}     %%<-- note 2 X columns.
```

Here `X` columns provide you the columns with equal width where contents break upon reaching the end.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\centering


\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{lXX}

 \toprule
Conditions & Items test corrects & Items test incorrects \\
 \midrule
 Non-adjacents & Fa\textunderscore Sol\textunderscore Ré\textunderscore (O\textunderscore P\textunderscore Q\textunderscore ) & *Do\#\textunderscore Sol\#\textunderscore Si (S\textunderscore R\textunderscore T) \\
 & Sol\#\textunderscore Do\#\textunderscore Si\textunderscore  (R\textunderscore S\textunderscore T) & *Ré\textunderscore Sol\textunderscore Fa (Q\textunderscore P\textunderscore O) \\
 & \textunderscore Do\textunderscore Fa\#\textunderscore Ré\# (\textunderscore u\textunderscore v\textunderscore w) & *La\textunderscore Mi\textunderscore La\# (\textunderscore y\textunderscore x\textunderscore z) \\
 & \textunderscore Mi\textunderscore La\textunderscore La\# (\textunderscore x\textunderscore y\textunderscore z) & *Ré\#\textunderscore Fa\#\textunderscore Do (\textunderscore w\textunderscore v\textunderscore u) \\
Adjacents &  Ré.Ré\#.Fa.Do.Sol.Fa\# (QwOuPv) & *Si.La.Sol\#.La\#.Do\#.Mi (TyRzSx) \\
 & Ré.La\#.Fa.Mi.Sol.La (QzOxPy) & *Si.Fa\#.Sol\#.Ré\#.Do\#.Do (TvRwSu) \\
 & Si.Ré\#.Sol\#.Do.Do\#.Fa\# (TwRuSv) & *Ré.La.Fa.La\#.Sol.Mi (QyOzPx) \\
 & Si.La\#.Sol\#.Mi.Do\#.La (TzRxSy) & *Ré.Fa\#.Fa.Ré\#.Sol.Do QvOwPu) \\
 \bottomrule

\end{tabularx}

\end{table}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]